# You should have heard of the answer

Tags: riddle, word

My prefix is used in many sports.
My infix is a short commanding officer.
My suffix is my suffix.
My whole is part of a badge.

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are a

> Legend

My prefix is used in many sports.

> **Leg**

My infix is a short commanding officer.

> **Gen** = short for General

My suffix is my suffix.

> **End**

My whole is part of a badge.

> **Legend** = an inscription, e.g, on a badge.
>  There is also a badge on Stack Exchange called "Legendary" which the question asker, Rand al'Thor, was the first (and so far only) to achieve on this site.

Title

> Legend is also an extremely famous or notorious person or a traditional story of questionable authenticity

Comment: Correct again. My intended answer for the last line was a bit more ... contextual, but that works.

Comment: @Randal'Thor ah yes, okay, missed that.